# Crawl online directories and parse online pdf document to extract text in java

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, web-crawler, cloud

I need to be able to crawl an online directory such as for example this one `http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/` and whenever a pdf, docx, txt, or odt file come across the crawling, I need to be able to parse, and extract the text from it.

I am using `files.walk` in order to crawl around locally in my laptop, and `Apache Tika` library to parse text, and it works just fine, but I don't really know how can I do the same in an online directory.

Here's the code that goes through my PC and parses the files just so you guys have an idea of what I'm doing:

```
public static void GetFiles() throws IOException {
    //PathXml is the path directory such as  "/home/user/" that
    //is taken from an xml file .
    Files.walk(Paths.get(PathXml)).forEach(filePath -> { //Crawling process (Using Java 8)
        if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
            if (filePath.toString().endsWith(".pdf") || filePath.toString().endsWith(".docx") ||
                    filePath.toString().endsWith(".txt")){
                try {
                    TikaReader.ParsedText(filePath.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TikaException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(filePath);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and here's the TikaReader method:

```
public static String ParsedText(String file) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file); 
    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    try {
        parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
        System.out.println(handler.toString());
        return handler.toString();
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

So again, how can I do the same thing with the given online directory above?

Comment: You will need a web crawler. 
Check out https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j
See some examples and configure it in a way that it will visit every link in desired domain, but will only take action when page ends with .pdf, .docx, or .txt,

Comment: Yeah, I do know there are a few parsers around, but since it is a college project, I am not allowed to use third party "Heavy" libraries that can strongly simplify the work. But thank you for your response.

Comment: It is a little hard to define "heavy" isn't it? Anyways, another way to do it, which requires more work is to take HTML parsing library like jSoup and crawl through the <a> elements on your own.

Comment: Yes @pnadczuk, I've managed to crawl around with Jsoup. Now I just don't know how to actual parse the PDF file held online. Here is my second question about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998020/parse-text-from-pdf-txt-or-docx-file-from-url-without-downloading-it-in-java-8