# Parse text from Pdf, txt, or docx file from URL without downloading it in Java 8

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, stream, jsoup

I need to be able to parse the text contained in a file online with a given url, i.e. `http://website.com/document.pdf`.

I am making a search engine which basically can tell me if the searched word is in some file online, and retrieve the file's URL, so I don't need to download the file but to just read it.

I was looking for a way and found something with `InputStream` and `OpenConnection` but didn't managed to actually do it.

I am using jsoup in order to crawl around a website in order to retrieve the URLs, and I was trying to parse it with a Jsoup method, but it does not work.

So what is the best way to do this?

EDIT:

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
File in = new File("http://website.com/document.pdf");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(in, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use URL instead of file for access to the URL. So using Apache Tika you should be able to grab a string of the content this way.

```
import org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL("http://website.com/document.pdf");
        ContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        PDFParser pdfparser = new PDFParser();
        pdfparser.parse(is, contenthandler, metadata, new ParseContext());

        System.out.println(contenthandler.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: A PDF is **not** a text file. Your code is ok for text files but it will most likely break any binaries.

Comment: It kind of works, but it shows a lot of encoded characters instead of the actual text held inside the pdf file. Thank you for your response, but do you know how can I get the actual text?

Comment: Yes @mkl is right, there is I believe a library for parsing PDFs in java I will try and clear this up and edit my answer sorry for the mistakr

Comment: Downloading a binary go a `byte[]` can be done very similarly. You simply use the `InputStream` directly instead of wrapping it in a `Reader` and don't read into a buffer `String` but `byte[]`.

Comment: I am actually using Apache Tika, it works fine for me, it receives a string with the path pointing to the PDF file, naturally, the path I've given to the method is a local path, will it be possible to do the same with these online PDFs? (You can see my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982173/crawl-online-directories-and-parse-online-pdf-document-to-extract-text-in-java?noredirect=1#comment48118440_29982173 )

Comment: The method you point to immediately creates a `FileInputStream` for the file. Try using the `url.openStream()` from this answer instead.

Comment: @mkl is right if your method works for a file stream it should be ok to parse a stream from a URL.

Comment: I didn't knew it would work just the same way!

Thank you @mkl

Comment: pipedreams2, if @Jack verifies that it indeed works like this, you might want to add that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code first download the PDF file then read the text with apache lib. you need to add some jar manually. 
you need to set your local pdf file address which is by defualt "download.pdf".

```
import com.gnostice.pdfone.PdfDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class LoadDocumentFromURL {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        URL url1 = new URL("https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.06933.pdf");
        byte[] ba1 = new byte[1024];
        int baLength;
        FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream("download.pdf");
        try {
            // Contacting the URL
            // System.out.print("Connecting to " + url1.toString() + " ... ");
            URLConnection urlConn = url1.openConnection();
            // Checking whether the URL contains a PDF
            if (!urlConn.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("application/pdf")) {
                System.out.println("FAILED.\n[Sorry. This is not a PDF.]");
            } else {
                try {
                    // Read the PDF from the URL and save to a local file
                    InputStream is1 = url1.openStream();
                    while ((baLength = is1.read(ba1)) != -1) {
                        fos1.write(ba1, 0, baLength);
                    }
                    fos1.flush();
                    fos1.close();
                    is1.close();
                    // Load the PDF document and display its page count
                    //System.out.print("DONE.\nProcessing the PDF ... ");
                    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
                    try {
                        doc.load("download.pdf");
                        // System.out.println("DONE.\nNumber of pages in the PDF is " + doc.getPageCount());
                        // System.out.println(doc.getAuthor());
                        // System.out.println(doc.getKeywords());
                        // System.out.println(doc.toString());
                        doc.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("FAILED.\n[" + e.getMessage() + "]");
                    }
                } catch (ConnectException ce) {
                    //System.out.println("FAILED.\n[" + ce.getMessage() + "]\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            //System.out.println("FAILED.\n[" + npe.getMessage() + "]\n");
        }
        File file = new File("your local pdf file address which is download.pdf");
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
        System.out.println(text);
        document.close();
    }
}
```